# Join two tables without subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create sql query without subquery, here is working query:

```
select * from customers 
join 
(select idContactOwner, count(*) contacts_count 
from contacts GROUP BY idContactOwner HAVING contacts_count>5) k 
where customers.id=k.idContactOwner;
```

and here is what i'm trying but it doesn't work:

```
select idContactOwner, count(*) counter from contacts A
group by idContactOwner having counter>5 join customers B
on A.idContactOwner=B.id;
```

here is sql fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/724962/59

Comment: Sample data set, desired result please.

Comment: Both queries are same.

Comment: @snyder I'm sorry there was my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT A.idContactOwner, B.whatEverFields, count(A.idContactOwner) AS counter
FROM contacts A, customers B
WHERE A.idContactOwner=B.id 
GROUP BY A.idContactOwner 
HAVING counter>5;
```

Something like this?

Comment: Yes bullseye! You understood perfectly what i need! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

`group by` must come after `join`

```
select A.idContactOwner, count(*) counter 
from contacts A
join customers B on A.idContactOwner = B.id
group by A.idContactOwner 
having counter > 5
```

Comment: Thank you i didn't know. But @Jose Neves variant returns exactly what i need.